# How safe is it reading / copying a file which is being appended to?

Tags: linux

If a log file has events constantly being appended to it, how safe is it to read that file (or copy it) with another process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unix allows concurrent reading and writing.  It is totally safe to read a file while others are appending to it.

Of course it can happen that an appending act is unfinished while a reading act is reaching the end of the file, then this reader will get an incomplete version (e. g. only a part of a new log entry at the end of the file).  But technically, this is *correct* because the file really was in this state while it was being read (e. g. copied).

EDIT

There's more to it.

If a writer process has an open file handle, the file will stay on disk as long as this process keeps the open file handle.

If you remove the file (`rm(1)`, `unlink(2)`), it will be removed from its directory only.  It will stay on disk, and that writer (and everybody else who happens to have an open file handle) will still be able to read the contents of the already removed file.  Only after the last process closes its file handle, the file contents will be freed on the disk.

This is sometimes an issue if a process writes a large log file which is filling up the disk.  If it keeps and open file handle to the log file, the system administrator cannot free this disk capacity using `rm`. 
 A typical approach then is to kill the process as well.  Hence it is a good idea, as a process, to close the file handle for the log file again after writing to the log (or close and reopen it at least from time to time).

There's more:

If a process has a an open file handle on a log file, this file handle contains a position.  If now the log file is emptied (`truncate(1)`, `truncate(2)`, `open(2)` for writing not using append flags, `: > filepath`), the file's contents is indeed removed from the disk.  If the process having an open file handle is now writing to this file, it will write at the old position, e. g. at a position of several megabytes.  Doing this to an empty file will fill the gap with zeros.

This is no real problem, if a sparse file can be created (typically possible on Unix file systems).  Only otherwise will it fill the disk again quickly.  But in any case it can be very confusing.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed response! Is the open file handle a part of the linux ABI? And something abstracted away by the `open` method on C/Python?

Comment: The described handling of open file handles is part of Unix, so also part of Linux.  And it is *not* abstracted away by `open` in C/Python.  If a Python process holds an open file handle (created using `open()`), it will result in the described results.  Actually, it is an established pattern to create a file (`open('/tmp/foo.tmp', 'wb')`), then at once to remove it from disk (`unlink('/tmp/foo.tmp')`) and hold the open handle to have a temp file to write to and read from which is automatically removed from disk as soon as the process terminates.